# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-icons" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, download

I am trying to press a the download  on this page

[https://data.unwomen.org/data-portal/sdg?annex=All&finic[]=SUP_1_1_IPL_P&flocat[]=478&flocat[]=174&flocat[]=818&flocat[]=504&flocat[]=729&flocat[]=788&flocat[]=368&flocat[]=400&flocat[]=275&flocat[]=760&fys[]=2015&fyr[]=2030&fca[ALLAGE]=ALLAGE&fca[](https://data.unwomen.org/data-portal/sdg?annex=All&finic%5B%5D=SUP_1_1_IPL_P&flocat%5B%5D=478&flocat%5B%5D=174&flocat%5B%5D=818&flocat%5B%5D=504&flocat%5B%5D=729&flocat%5B%5D=788&flocat%5B%5D=368&flocat%5B%5D=400&flocat%5B%5D=275&flocat%5B%5D=760&fys%5B%5D=2015&fyr%5B%5D=2030&fca%5BALLAGE%5D=ALLAGE&fca%5B)<15Y]=<15Y&fca[15%2B]=15%2B&fca[15-24]=15-24&fca[25-34]=25-34&fca[35-54]=35-54&fca[55%2B]=55%2B&tab=table

i am using python selenium with firefox and this is what i tried:

````
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'SDG-Indicator-Dashboard')))
time.sleep(1)
download_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'float-buttons-wrap')
buttons = download_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
buttons_attributes = [i.get_attribute('title') for i in buttons]
download_button_index = buttons_attributes.index('Download')
buttons[download_button_index].location_once_scrolled_into_view
buttons[download_button_index].click()```

i keep getting the same error:
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-icons" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view

eventho i am getting the correct element and i tried using js like this:
```driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)```

also did not work.
````

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the XPath, try the below code:

```
driver.get("https://data.unwomen.org/data-portal/sdg?annex=All&finic[]=SUP_1_1_IPL_P&flocat[]=478&flocat[]=174&flocat[]=818&flocat[]=504&flocat[]=729&flocat[]=788&flocat[]=368&flocat[]=400&flocat[]=275&flocat[]=760&fys[]=2015&fyr[]=2030&fca[ALLAGE]=ALLAGE&fca[<15Y]=<15Y&fca[15%2B]=15%2B&fca[15-24]=15-24&fca[25-34]=25-34&fca[35-54]=35-54&fca[55%2B]=55%2B&tab=table")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
time.sleep(2)
download_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//button[@type='button' and @title='Download'])[2]")
download_btn.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
download_btn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to make sure you are giving enough time to complete page loading
2.Once you started to find button element , it's better to use `try/catch` blocks multiple times and put sleep function when exception occures to provide appropriate time to load scripts and elements.
3.Try finding by `xpath` instead of finding elements by indexes and be aware that you need to use the index [1] instead of [0] in a `xpath` string